# Determining the available amount of RAM on an iOS device

Tags: xcode, ios, memory, memory-management

You've likely seen the many "System Info" apps out there which display things like remaining battery life, and even system info like memory, etc.

In a similar manner, is there any way to retrieve the current amount of available RAM from my app so that I can make better decisions on when it's best to dump or keep certain views to avoid memory warnings?

Comment: Or maybe you haven’t searched well enough ;-) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3823266/is-it-legal-to-use-the-well-known-free-memory-code-in-ipad-iphone-app

Comment: @Bavarious: The answers to that and other related questions largely miss the point, which is that you might want to use more RAM to make your app more responsive or media-rich, etc., but only on devices that can comfortably accommodate the extra load. The advice to "profile" and "use less RAM" doesn't cut it.

Comment: @Eric: I had a similar issue and ended up finding an answer myself. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8072278/9990). Note that I was looking for total system RAM; I don't if that's the same as your requirement, but I hope this helps.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Programmatically retrieve memory usage on iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/787160/programmatically-retrieve-memory-usage-on-iphone)

Comment: **See [only solution for extensions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57315975/8740349)** (without wrong result)

Answer (score 139, accepted):

```
#import <mach/mach.h>
#import <mach/mach_host.h>

void print_free_memory ()
{
    mach_port_t host_port;
    mach_msg_type_number_t host_size;
    vm_size_t pagesize;

    host_port = mach_host_self();
    host_size = sizeof(vm_statistics_data_t) / sizeof(integer_t);
    host_page_size(host_port, &pagesize);        

    vm_statistics_data_t vm_stat;

    if (host_statistics(host_port, HOST_VM_INFO, (host_info_t)&vm_stat, &host_size) != KERN_SUCCESS) {
        NSLog(@"Failed to fetch vm statistics");
    }

    /* Stats in bytes */ 
    natural_t mem_used = (vm_stat.active_count +
                          vm_stat.inactive_count +
                          vm_stat.wire_count) * pagesize;
    natural_t mem_free = vm_stat.free_count * pagesize;
    natural_t mem_total = mem_used + mem_free;
    NSLog(@"used: %u free: %u total: %u", mem_used, mem_free, mem_total);
}
```

Please note that this call does not account for memory that is being used by the gpu. If you are seeing a size that is smaller than expected system ram. It is more than likely allocated graphics memory.

Comment: I'm shocked that I'm the first person to give you a point on this code. Its working great on my iPhone and is a huge help to me! I wish  I could give you 10 points!!!

Comment: I did find one other command you can add to the above, to get task stats:   struct task_basic_info info;
  if(dump_memory_usage(&info)) {
   fm.resident_size = (size_t)info.resident_size;
   fm.virtual_size = (size_t)info.virtual_size;
  }

Comment: If you want to true TOTAL RAM the device has, just use [NSProcessInfo processInfo].physicalMemory.

Comment: @Steve,
 Provides the amount of physical memory on the computer.
- (unsigned long long)physicalMemory

How does this tell you how much memory your application is using?

Comment: @Nico, it doesn't. It tells the total system RAM. I recommend this instead of mem_total/mem_free, not instead of mem_used. This is because mem_total/mem_free depend on how much RAM is being used by other apps to, and so it's a completely unreliable indicator for pretty much anything.

Comment: @Steve The nice part about mem_total is shrinks graphics memory is allocated

Comment: There are no private apis called here so yes.

Comment: Has anyone check that this code works correct at 64bit devices?

Comment: I believe the total memory calculation is inaccurate. Cross-reference it with `[NSProcessInfo processInfo].physicalMemory` and you'll see the latter is more closely aligned with the device's marketed memory spec.

Comment: @Nico which one is relevant NSProcessInfo processInfo].physicalMemory ,this one gives in bytes?

Comment: YES. NSProcessInfo processInfo].physicalMemory returns you total RAM size in bytes.

Answer (score 14):

This works in Swift 4.

The really important difference here is: It casts to Int64 before multiplying, because otherwise you get quickly overflows, especially if you run it in a simulator where it uses the PC Memory.

```
var pagesize: vm_size_t = 0

let host_port: mach_port_t = mach_host_self()
var host_size: mach_msg_type_number_t = mach_msg_type_number_t(MemoryLayout<vm_statistics_data_t>.stride / MemoryLayout<integer_t>.stride)
host_page_size(host_port, &pagesize)

var vm_stat: vm_statistics = vm_statistics_data_t()
withUnsafeMutablePointer(to: &vm_stat) { (vmStatPointer) -> Void in
    vmStatPointer.withMemoryRebound(to: integer_t.self, capacity: Int(host_size)) {
        if (host_statistics(host_port, HOST_VM_INFO, $0, &host_size) != KERN_SUCCESS) {
            NSLog("Error: Failed to fetch vm statistics")
        }
    }
}

/* Stats in bytes */
let mem_used: Int64 = Int64(vm_stat.active_count +
        vm_stat.inactive_count +
        vm_stat.wire_count) * Int64(pagesize)
let mem_free: Int64 = Int64(vm_stat.free_count) * Int64(pagesize)
```

Comment: Hello
I tried your example but I have very different values for mem_used. When I convert it to MB, it gives me 120MB while in XCode, it gives me 30MB. Any idea why?

Comment: Thanks for this. Just a comment, I think the Int64 should be UInt64.

Comment: @Minos I disagree. Remember that 2^63 is already 9,223,372,036,854,775,808 and Int64 has as signed integer the advantage that some subtractions won't produce exceptions when going below 0.

Comment: Why `MemoryLayout.stride` instead of `MemoryLayout.size`?

Answer (score 4):

You can check the available RAM Memory in an iOS devices

```
    #import mach\mach.h
    #import mach\mach_host.h

     static natural_t get_free_memory(void)  
     {  
       mach_port_t host_port;  
       mach_msg_type_number_t host_size;  
       vm_size_t pagesize;  
       host_port = mach_host_self();  
       host_size = sizeof(vm_statistics_data_t) / sizeof(integer_t);  
       host_page_size(host_port, &pagesize);  
       vm_statistics_data_t vm_stat;  
       if (host_statistics(host_port, HOST_VM_INFO, (host_info_t)&vm_stat, &host_size) != KERN_SUCCESS)  
       {  
         NSLog(@"Failed to fetch vm statistics");  
         return 0;  
       }  
       /* Stats in bytes */  
       natural_t mem_free = vm_stat.free_count * pagesize;  
       return mem_free;  
     }
```

Comment: Do you know, this takes in account memory used by GPU, or no?

Comment: why backslashes in mach\mach.h ?