# How to get available memory in IOS ?

Tags: ios, memory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get information about free memory and running processes in an App Store approved app? (Yes, there is one!)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8275578/how-to-get-information-about-free-memory-and-running-processes-in-an-app-store-a)

How to get available memory in IOS ? I don't know..

I googled, then I know how can i get the physical memory, user memory and used mem, free mem in VM.

But. the memory size is different with which is Settings -> General -> About -> Avaliable.

I want to know "Avaliable" in Settings.

Have a nice day .

Comment: I think you mean "available storage" -- http://stackoverflow.com/a/8036586/603256

Comment: Does the following work for you?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5012886/knowing-available-ram-on-an-ios-device

Comment: Oh. I see. That's right. "available storage"...  but one more question. I got the "available storage" use behind the method, but a little different .. always 200MB or 160MB. why .. ? help me ..

Answer (score 1):

found this on here a few months back cant remember who originally posted. Is this what you are looking for?

```
- (uint64_t)freeDiskspace
{
uint64_t totalSpace = 0;
uint64_t totalFreeSpace = 0;

__autoreleasing NSError *error = nil;  
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);  
NSDictionary *dictionary = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] attributesOfFileSystemForPath:[paths lastObject] error: &error];  

if (dictionary) {  
    NSNumber *fileSystemSizeInBytes = [dictionary objectForKey: NSFileSystemSize];  
    NSNumber *freeFileSystemSizeInBytes = [dictionary objectForKey:NSFileSystemFreeSize];
    totalSpace = [fileSystemSizeInBytes unsignedLongLongValue];
    totalFreeSpace = [freeFileSystemSizeInBytes unsignedLongLongValue];
    NSLog(@"Memory Capacity of %llu MiB with %llu MiB Free memory available.", ((totalSpace/1024ll)/1024ll), ((totalFreeSpace/1024ll)/1024ll));
   } else {  
    NSLog(@"Error Obtaining System Memory Info: Domain = %@, Code = %@", [error domain], [error code]);  
}  

return totalFreeSpace;
}
```