# CPU and Memory usage of a method call in iPhone

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory, cpu-usage

I am trying to add some performance stats to a method call for my iPhone app. I used the following to find the time to process:

```
#define TICK   NSDate *startTime = [NSDate date]
#define TOCK   NSLog(@"Time to process: %f", -[startTime timeIntervalSinceNow])
```

Are there similar strategies to measure CPU and memory usage of a method call?

Comment: What is that hyphen doing there? (`..., -[startTime timeIntervalSinceNow])`)

Comment: Negate the value returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are going to have to do some work to get this working but here's how you can do it.

- From this SO [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8223348/ios-get-cpu-usage-from-application) you can learn how to get the current CPU usage.
- From this SO [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5012886/knowing-available-ram-on-an-ios-device) you can learn how to get the current Memory usage.

Now you can spawn a new thread that checks the CPU and memory periodically or on-demand, then create a class, something like this:

```
@interface ProfilerBlock
-(id) init;
-(void) end;
@end
```

- The *init* method should initialize the current time and register the *ProfilerBlock* instance to get information from the worker thread about memory usage and CPU usage.
- The *end* method should calculate the time and print all the needed information or write it to a file or something :)

Now create a C-Style releasing function for the *ProfilerBlock* class

```
static void __$_Profiler_Block_Release_Object_$__(ProfilerBlock **obj) // the long name is just to prevent duplicated symbol names //
{
    [(*obj) end];
    [(*obj) release];
    (*obj) = nil;
}
```

Finally you can create macros to make your life easier:

```
#define CONCAT2(x, y) x ## y
#define CONCAT(x, y) CONCAT2(x, y)
#define PROFILER_SCOPE_OBJECT __attribute__((cleanup(__$_Profiler_Block_Release_Object_$__)))
#define PROFILE_BLOCK ProfilerBlock *CONCAT(__profilerBlock_, __LINE__) PROFILER_SCOPE_OBJECT = [[ProfilerBlock alloc] init];
```

Once you have all this, you can profile methods like this:

```
-(void) methodToProfile
{
    PROFILE_BLOCK
    // add some code to profile here //
    // the "end" function will get called automatically after the method is done, even if you return early, allowing you to process the profiled data //
}
```

I hope this helps, sorry if I didn't go in detail about how to meassure memory and CPU but I believe it is well covered in the other answers.

Answer (score 2):

Use `Instruments` to check your app's performance. Apple has done a pretty decent job, so no need to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Actually, there is a lot of value in tracking execution times of large grained tasks over time across many environments.  Having to use Instruments always is quite prohibitive.

Answer (score 1):

Use Instruments to take these measurements in real-life usage on a real-life device.

Answer (score 0):

```
 NSTimeInterval t1 = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970];
```

.... custom processes ...

```
 NSTimeInterval t2 = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970];
 NSTimeInterval dt = t2-t1; this is in milisec;
```