# iOS: Check if system has enough memory

Tags: ios, objective-c

In C, you can check if the system has enough free memory by checking the return value of a call to malloc(). How do you check if the system has enough free memory in Objective-C? Does alloc throw an exception if there is not enough memory?

I have created a class that derives from NSObject for an in-memory photo cache. I need to check before saving something into the cache if there is enough memory, and can't quite figure out the proper way to do so.

Thanks

Comment: you may check available memory as it does  print_free_memory function in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5012886/knowing-available-ram-on-an-ios-device

Answer (score 1):

`-alloc` will return `nil` if it is unable to allocate the memory requested. Just check that the return value is non-nil.

Comment: What would you recommend to do for this if I am doing a `[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:]` call? Will this return `nil` if there is not enough free memory?

Comment: Yes. Any method that allocates memory like that should return `nil` if it fails to allocate the memory.