# Total RAM size of an iOS device

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

Is it possible to determine actual RAM size of an iOS device?

Referring to this question [Determining the available amount of RAM on an iOS device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5012886/knowing-available-ram-on-an-ios-device/8540665) we can determine the available free memory but how to get the actual total size.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

The simplest solution to find total RAM in a device is to use `NSProcessInfo`:

**Objective C:**

```
[NSProcessInfo processInfo].physicalMemory
```

**Swift 3**:

```
NSProcessInfo.processInfo().physicalMemory
```

**Swift 5**:

```
ProcessInfo.processInfo.physicalMemory
```

Note: `physicalMemory` gives us the information at bytes and can be less than the actual devices memory. To calculate GB, divide by **`1024³`** *(1073741824)* and round up to the closes integer:

```
Int(round(Double(physicalMemory) / (1024.0 * 1024.0 * 1024.0)))
```

As documented [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSProcessInfo_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSProcessInfo/physicalMemory).

Comment: @Woodstock how to convert into GB       [NSProcessInfo processInfo].physicalMemory / (1024.0 * 1024.0 * 1024.0)];
, this returns around 16 GB for simualator in ios6s ,and expected is around 2GB

Comment: @SrishtiRoy yes, it returns in bytes, on my 16GB MacBook Pro I get: 17179869184 bytes, which I divide by 1073741824, to convert bytes to gigabytes and get 16.

Comment: @Woodstock yes similar here ,is it because i am using simulator in xcode

Comment: @SrishtiRoy yes, it will show the RAM of your host machine.

Comment: Are these 8bit bytes?

Comment: @confused yes, always 8bits in a byte these days.

Comment: Cheers. Progress... stopped, seemingly in 1984. I'd like to bite more bits. Like a MegaDrive.

Comment: Interesting: just ran this on my new 14 Pro Max: 5. So does that mean Apple carves out 1GB that apps can't touch?

Answer (score 2):

Slight change for Swift 3:
`ProcessInfo.processInfo.physicalMemory`

Answer (score 1):

Following code is to get memory in GB

Objective-C

```
NSProcessInfo.processInfo.physicalMemory / (1024.0 * 1024.0 * 1024.0);
```

Swift

```
NSProcessInfo.processInfo().physicalMemory / (1024.0 * 1024.0 * 1024.0)
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is right there in [the top answer of the question you linked](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8540665/361247):

```
natural_t mem_used = (vm_stat.active_count +
                      vm_stat.inactive_count +
                      vm_stat.wire_count) * pagesize;
natural_t mem_free = vm_stat.free_count * pagesize;
natural_t mem_total = mem_used + mem_free;
NSLog(@"used: %u free: %u total: %u", mem_used, mem_free, mem_total);
```

Comment: mem_total value is not same always

Comment: Yeah, I think John's solution is much better.