# Programmatically determining current process’ memory usage on iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, unit-testing, memory, swift

I am trying to find a way to programmatically determine the memory usage of my current process. and I could not find it neither on XCode’s documentation nor on other questions in StackOverflow.
I want to do that because:
    1. my app may be caching significant amount of data in memory 
    2. I want my app to respond to memory warnings by releasing as much memory as possible
    3. I want to be able to write unit tests to check that this behavior is working fine
So I need my unit test to be able to measure current process memory before and after the memory warning message is received and processed.
Does anyone know how to handle that ?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5012886/determining-the-available-amount-of-ram-on-an-ios-device.