# How to figure out how many other apps are running in the background?

Tags: iphone, ios, performance, ipad, memory-management

My friends are making a high-performance game which will lag if many other apps are running.

Is there a way to figure out how many apps are running in the background right now? There's the app called Activity Monitor Touch which shows all background processes, and it has been approved for the AppStore. It even shows the icons of the background apps. I guess it accesses the small icons for spotlight.

It shows the usage of Wired, Active, Inactive and Free memory as well as total free disk space.

I always thought that's impossible until I've seen this app!

So the idea is this: Check how much free memory is available to the app, and how many background apps are running. Then tell the user that performance may lag due to this, and suggest terminating some of them.

Comment: You might want to take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3823266/is-it-legal-to-use-the-well-known-free-memory-code-in-ipad-iphone-app

Comment: iOS will free up memory used by other apps if you get low on memory.  Don't try to go around the OS, just let it work.  Now if someone is running streaming music in the background that will take CPU and might be an issue, but if you intentionally kill someone's Pandora they might not like it.

Answer (score 1):

Determine how many apps run in background: (use xcode)

```
mach_port_t *p = (mach_port_t *)SBSSpringBoardServerPort();
char frontmostAppS[256];
memset(frontmostAppS,sizeof(frontmostAppS),0);
SBFrontmostApplicationDisplayIdentifier(p,frontmostAppS);
NSString * frontmostApp=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s",frontmostAppS];
NSLog(@"Frontmost app is %@",frontmostApp);
//get list of running apps from SpringBoard
NSArray *allApplications = SBSCopyApplicationDisplayIdentifiers(p,NO, NO);
for(NSString *identifier in allApplications)
{
    NSString *locName = SBSCopyLocalizedApplicationNameForDisplayIdentifier(identifier);
    NSLog(@"identifier:%@, locName:%@",identifier,locName);
}
```