# How to get information about free memory and running processes in an App Store approved app? (Yes, there is one!)

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, memory, process

There is an app called "Activity Monitor Touch" in the App Store, which displays background processes as well as free memory.

So there MUST be an public API to access this information. The evidence:

[image: evidence]

[image: evidence]

I'm already searching for days but can't find any good starting point. How can this app figure all this stuff out without any jailbreaking / hacking / etc.?

Until recently I was sure that something like this is absolutely impossible on iOS.

I've [found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4312613/can-we-retrieve-the-applications-currently-running-in-iphone-and-ipad/4312705#4312705) this code snippet:

```
- (NSArray *)runningProcesses {

    int mib[4] = {CTL_KERN, KERN_PROC, KERN_PROC_ALL, 0};
    size_t miblen = 4;

    size_t size;
    int st = sysctl(mib, miblen, NULL, &size, NULL, 0);

    struct kinfo_proc * process = NULL;
    struct kinfo_proc * newprocess = NULL;

    do {

        size += size / 10;
        newprocess = realloc(process, size);

        if (!newprocess){

            if (process){
                free(process);
            }

            return nil;
        }

        process = newprocess;
        st = sysctl(mib, miblen, process, &size, NULL, 0);

    } while (st == -1 && errno == ENOMEM);

    if (st == 0){

        if (size % sizeof(struct kinfo_proc) == 0){
            int nprocess = size / sizeof(struct kinfo_proc);

            if (nprocess){

                NSMutableArray * array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

                for (int i = nprocess - 1; i >= 0; i--){

                    NSString * processID = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%d", process[i].kp_proc.p_pid];
                    NSString * processName = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%s", process[i].kp_proc.p_comm];

                    NSDictionary * dict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjects:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:processID, processName, nil] 
                                                                        forKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"ProcessID", @"ProcessName", nil]];
                    [processID release];
                    [processName release];
                    [array addObject:dict];
                    [dict release];
                }

                free(process);
                return [array autorelease];
            }
        }
    }

    return nil;
}
```

But I can't make it run on the iPhone. Xcode doesn't know these symbols:
CTL_KERN, KERN_PROC, KERN_PROC_ALL

So of course I must import a header file or library. Does anyone know where these belong to, and how the headers must be imported to make this work?

Comment: [potentially related question linked here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3823266/is-it-legal-to-use-the-well-known-free-memory-code-in-ipad-iphone-app)

Comment: But is it officially allowed by Apple to use it?! Maybe the Apps in Store just had luck to get into?!

Comment: This app is no longer available.  But using sysctl is not banned from apps. See a bunch of apps that do similar stuff. Search for activity monitor on iOS store.

Comment: There's an app currently in the Appstore that lists all the running apps and even shows the app icons. The app can also "free up" unused memory and "clean up" disk cache. See app Battery Doctor.

Comment: @dontWatchMyProfile So you actually can know the name of the app running with this?

Comment: how do they get applications icons?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Works like a charm:

```
#import <sys/sysctl.h>
```

Comment: Any alternatives for iOS 9?

Answer (score 31):

`sysctl` is no longer accessible to sandboxed iOS 9 apps.

From WWDC 2015 session 703 Privacy and Your App:

> In iOS 9, the sandbox now prevents a process from accessing the
>   kern.proc, kern.procargs, and kern.procargs2 values for other
>   processes

and

> iOS apps are not permitted to see what other apps are running

So even if you find a way, you are likely to get rejected from the App Store.

https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015-703/

Comment: Thank you Ad Networks. This is why we can't have nice things. Yes, China, I'm looking in your general direction.