# How does clueful get a list of all installed iOS applications?

Tags: ios, ipc, sandbox

I just installed [Clueful by BitDefender on iOS](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/clueful/id512467899?mt=8). This application scans all the installed applications on my iPhone.

Given that iOS sandboxes all app data and my app cannot access other installed apps, how does Clueful pull it  off?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BitDefender only checks if a [URL Scheme](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/ios-sdk-working-with-url-schemes/) for the installed app exists.

you can check if an installed app supports a URL with:

```
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:[url absoluteURL]]) {
    //Your code
}
```

here is a [Wiki](http://wiki.akosma.com/IPhone_URL_Schemes) with many known URL Schemes

Answer (score 2):

You can get a list of running processes (take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8275578/how-to-get-information-about-free-memory-and-running-processes-in-an-app-store-a) for an example) and their names. In order to get the images and real app names, you have to match these on some server (that stores a list with products and their process names).