# network connections made by my application in iOS?

Tags: ios, macos, network-programming

I was just wondering if i can get number of network connections(hits to my server) made by my application? i am able to get my application information(process name and id) when it is in background with the help of this link [running process list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8275578/how-to-get-information-about-free-memory-and-running-processes-in-an-app-store-a)

But the **struct kp_proc** has many subprocesses which have there own subprocesses. so i am not able to guess which particular key will show my network connections list?? Any idea anyone?some process for example[image: some process for example]

Comment: Are you making the network connections?

Comment: yes for my app only in which i am making connections

Answer (score 0):

What are you using to make requests? if you are using the native framework so NSURLConnection you can override in a subclass the methods:

```
+ (NSData *)sendSynchronousRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request returningResponse:(NSURLResponse **)response error:(NSError **)error

+ (void)sendAsynchronousRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request queue:(NSOperationQueue *)queue completionHandler:(void (^)(NSURLResponse*, NSData*, NSError*))handler

- (void)start
```

and increment a global value to take trace about how many connection have you started during the life time of your application, probably is not the best solution because this not consider the failure, another solution could be use some analytic service like newrelic or similar

Answer (score 0):

Try PonyDebugger, its not perfect, but among many other functions, it shows all all internet calls the app is making https://github.com/square/PonyDebugger

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `lsof` (list open files) can be useful to you. It can display open connections (open sockets indeed) for a specific process, eg. for process 99340:

```
$ lsof -i -a -p 99340
```