# How do I get notified when user starts messaging or mailing app in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios

Actually I want to build such a iOS app which will give alert if user start **sms application** or **messaging application** when he is driving more than certain speed limit. As I am new in iOS development I don't know whether it is feasible or not?

Basically my id:

Q: How do I get notified when user starts **messaging app**?

Comment: You mean in game? What do you actually mean with driving here?

Comment: You can monitor the list of running processes in the device [using this code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8275578/how-to-get-information-about-free-memory-and-running-processes-in-an-app-store-a). Search for a specific process in the list, when found you can notify the user based on your condition. I cannot confirm if this will be accepted by Apple for App store or not.

Answer (score 1):

Due to iOS sandboxing restrictions, you cannot get any information from your app regarding launching or usage of any other apps.

---

The only way to do this would be if you were the developer of both apps. In that case you could use an external server to log when each of the apps is launched and then get this information from the converse app.