# Find out what process launched the user

Tags: ios, memory, process

I've found a function here to get all the running processes
[How to get information about free memory and running processes in an App Store approved app? (Yes, there is one!)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8275578/how-to-get-information-about-free-memory-and-running-processes-in-an-app-store-a)

but obviously there's a lot of system process.

Is There a way to get the running processes that the user launched?

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tried it, but if you read the manual (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/system/conceptual/manpages_iphoneos/man3/sysctl.3.html) it looks like you could replace KERN_PROC_ALL with KERN_PROC_UID...

Comment: You mean something like this? int mib[4] = {CTL_KERN, KERN_PROC, KERN_PROC_UID, 0}; so it show some system processes but not the app launched by the user

Comment: Yep, except you need to place the user ID in the last slot instead of 0.

Comment: Ok, now I have int mib[4] = {CTL_KERN, KERN_PROC, KERN_PROC_UID, getuid()}; but it returns 125 processes but I have only 4 opened apps.

Comment: Hmm, I see.  I guess this is not the right answer.  Maybe someone else has a better idea.