# Is there any way to programatically find out which apps are launched by user?

Tags: ios

I am developing an app and there is requirement to know which app are launched by user.  At any given point of time I would like to know which apps user is launching ( such as FB, Instagram, Candy Crush Saga etc. ) .

I did google quite a bit , however could not find any reference to do it.  I did find reference to sys/sysctl.h and then finding running process and mapping process id to map name ( [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8275578/how-to-get-information-about-free-memory-and-running-processes-in-an-app-store-a/8276502#8276502) )

I wanted to check if there is alternative and/or better/more efficient way of doing this.

Comment: AppStore safe? No. `sysctl` isn't safe either.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is **NO**.

However you can get a list of **running processesn name** (not the whole application name's or titles). So there may be same names for different applications.