# Swift: Is there a way to get the running apps in IOS?

Tags: ios, swift

Is there a way to get the running apps info or the action of openning the app in IOS? There is a way to do that in android with getRunningTasks, maybe there is a way to do that in ios?

Comment: From https://stackoverflow.com/a/31150824/1187415: *"iOS apps are not permitted to see what other apps are running"*

Answer (score 0):

At last in non-jailbroken iOS there is no such possibility. The reason is to protect users privacy - app should not know about other apps that are installed on user device (otherwise it could eg. spot business rivals app).