# Is it possible to get the current App the user is using, while my App is running on background?

Tags: ios

I want to built an App that helps people to figure out their App usages and perhaps reduce spending time on Apps they don't want to, in order to do that, I need to track it, so I give the user notifications if it crosses a certain value etc.

Is that possible somehow on IOS? If so, how? I've heard Facebook does something to figure out what apps do users do have. I promise I'm using it for a better reason than facebook(perhaps, to kill it).

Comment: I highly doubt it. That would give so many developers access to some very personal information about the user. *You* might have good intentions, but there would be plenty of people who wouldn't.

Comment: There is a built in Apple app that sort of does this, try checking this thread out although it looks like this may have been deprecated:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8275578/how-to-get-information-about-free-memory-and-running-processes-in-an-app-store-a

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since iOS 9, any app cannot see what other apps are using/doing/executing.